# Handling multiple checkboxes with ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a menu with multiple options that can be selected using `checkboxes` in `AngularJS`.
I've modelled my `DB` with 2 attributes that I want to use in my logic;
`min_selection_points` and `max_selection_points`. The idea is that I will use these to track how many of my `checkboxes` have been selected and once the `max_selection_points` have been reached I'll then disable the rest of the `checkboxes`.

So assuming I've got 6 `checkboxes` and `max_selection_points = 2`, when 2 checkboxes are checked I disable the 4 remaining `checkboxes` when 1 is deselected then I re-enable them all because the number of selection hasn't reached 2 which is the max. I intend to use `min_selection_points` as validation when a `button` is pressed so I want to be able to count the number of checked boxes or have a `bool` set when `max_selection_points` is reached... this is my code so far;

```
<div class="group-items" ng-if="modifier.max_selection_points > 1 || (modifier.max_selection_points == 1 && modifier.min_selection_points == 0)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in modifier.menu_modifier_items" class="modifier-item multiple">
        <label for="<%modifier.id + '_' + item.id%>">
            <input id="<%modifier.id + '_' + item.id%>"
                   class="checkbox-branded"
                   type="checkbox"
                   name="<%item.name%>"
                   ng-model="item.selected"
                   ng-class="{'not-available': !item.available}"
                   title="<%item.name%>"
                   value="<%item.id%>">
    <span class="item-name">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
        <span ng-bind="priceDelta(modifier, item)"></span>
    </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe I will need to use `ng-click` and `ng-change` to implement this logic so I have:

```
ng-click="modifierClicked(item)"
ng-change="modifierSelected(item)"
```

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function that returns the number of checked checkboxes:

```
$scope.Checked = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.modifier.menu_modifier_items, function(item){
        count += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return count; 
}
```

Then you can have an ng-disabled on every input:

```
ng-disabled="!item.selected && Checked== modifier.max_selection_points"
```

You can try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l923YJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer proposed Lucas Rodriguez right, but the plunker is weird.

```js
$scope.max_selection_points = 2;

$scope.questions = [{
  id: 21,
  answer: "Chicago"
}, {
  id: 22,
  answer: "New York"
}, {
  id: 23,
  answer: "Los Angeles"
}, {
  id: 24,
  answer: "London"
}, {
  id: 25,
  answer: "Moskva"
}];
$scope.countChecked = function() {
  var count_ = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(quest) {
    if (quest.checked)
      count_++;
  });
  return count_;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
  <label>
    <input ng-disabled="!question.checked && max_selection_points==countChecked()" type="checkbox" ng-model="question.checked">{{ question.answer }}
    <br/>
  </label>
</div>
```

This is correct [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3I5WKObH3JoYaRc5APBv?p=preview).